# Resize uploaded picture

Tags: php, image

```
if (move_uploaded_file($File_Tmp,"product_images/".$File_Name)) {
     // To Rename the uploaded file
    $Random = rand()*1200;
    $File_New_Name = $Random.".".$File_Extension;
    rename("product_images/".$File_Name,"product_images/".$File_New_Name);  
}
```

Now I want the uploaded image to be a custom defined size. Please help me write me the code with an explanation on how it works...Thanks ... PHP only code please.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "write my code for me" site. We are here to help troubleshoot and provide guidance when your when into design issues or implementation problems, but the expectation is that you have put some amount of effort into solving the problem yourself first.  So do you have any idea about how you might go about doing this?

Comment: What have you try ? where are not here to work for you :)

Comment: What all have you tried so far?  Have you looked into GD or imagick with php yet?  A basic google search for "php resize image" provides heaps of tutorials and examples.

Comment: actually i have no idea about this how to do this...as i said i m a beginner...If you cannot write a code, can you please guide me how to do this so that i'll try by my self and if it wont work i'll ask

Comment: And, you ..  Make me a sandwich ..  I've never done it before, and I'm hungry.

Comment: You can try to use `exec()` in php to run an external tool or use imagemagik (which is a tool that allow you to do a lot of things on images). exec documetation : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php and imageMagik : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.imagick.php

Comment: i think i asked it in a wrong way :P you guys taking it wrong :\ i m not asking to work for me :\ infact askin help

Comment: @MatRt thanks let me see how to use it ..

Comment: Add a response with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed this tutorial by Jarrod, and got great results. It includes error catching for the input image type.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

An exemple with imageMagik

```
<?php

    $image = new Imagick($filename);
    $image->resizeImage(200,200, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
    $image->writeImage($filename);

?>
```

Read the documentation here : [resizeImage](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/imagick.resizeimage.php)

And the installation documentation : [Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php)